# Dealing with "dealing with".

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

I am writing an academic paper, and I don't know which of the two forms are more suitable and/or correct.

"The question should be dealt with using different tools and methods."

*or*

"The question should be dealt with different tools and methods."

Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest using an active rather than passive voice.

Comment: Sadly most international academic papers  prefer such impersonal expressions.

Comment: To *deal* something and to *deal with* something mean different things. I suspect you want *[deal with](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/deal?q=deal+with#deal__17)* here, but you haven't told us what you intend to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase **"dealt with"** can be replaced with the word **"handled"**, as they are synonyms.

Make that replacement and you will see that your second sentence doesn't make any sense.  The first sentence is correct.

Comment: In fact I used handled. It felt more academic.